# Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this query which works correctly in MySQL.  More background on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051927/sql-to-find-most-popular-category/1055859#1055859).

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(ABS(v.vote)) AS score
FROM categories c,items i, votes v
    WHERE c.id = i.category_id
    AND i.id = v.voteable_id
    AND v.created_at > '#{1.week.ago}'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 8;
```

I tried running it in PostgreSQL, and it failed with this error message.

> PGError: ERROR: column "c.name" must
>   appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

I wasn't sure what this meant, so I tried changing "c.id" to "c.name" in the group by clause (both work in MySQL the same, assuming the name of an item is unique).

However this just produced another similar error

> PGError: ERROR: column "c.id" must
>   appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Oddly, it seems that this is now allowed in Postgre 9.1

Comment: Was it removed in Postgre 9.2? I'm getting this error for the same reasons.

Comment: @Aaron: it was not removed but works only when (quoting the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)): _the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column.  A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to list column names in SELECT which you are grouping in:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, SUM(ABS(v.vote)) AS score
FROM categories c,items i, votes v
  WHERE c.id = i.category_id
  AND i.id = v.voteable_id
  AND v.created_at > '#{1.week.ago}'
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 8;
```

"It is not permissible to include column names in a SELECT clause that are not referenced in the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: It is permissible in MySQL and that's why he's confused.  Horrible feature in my opinion

Answer (score 9):

I just had that issue but going from MySQL to SQL Server.  I thought the fact that it is allowed it was strange!

Yes, in most databases, when you have a GROUP BY clause you can only select aggregates of columns or columns that appear in the GROUP BY clause.  This is because it has no way of knowing if the other columns you're selecting are truly unique or not.

Just put the columns you want in the GROUP BY if they are indeed unique.  This was a "feature" of MySQL that was questionable.

You can read about MySQL's behavior and how it is different [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Example:

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(ABS(v.vote)) AS score
FROM categories c,items i, votes v
    WHERE c.id = i.category_id
    AND i.id = v.voteable_id
    AND v.created_at > '#{1.week.ago}'
GROUP BY c.id, c.name, c.whatever_else
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 8;
```

Comment: Thanks for the MySQL link, it makes more sense now!  In this case my c.id is always unique so it was probably ok, but at least I know now why they did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you change your statement to this it should work:

```
SELECT c.id, SUM(ABS(v.vote)) AS score
FROM categories c,items i, votes v
  WHERE c.id = i.category_id
  AND i.id = v.voteable_id
  AND v.created_at > '#{1.week.ago}'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 8;
```

I'm not sure what MySQL gives as a result, but to give you a very small example of why this does not work in PostgreSQL, take a look at the following `categories` table:

```
id | name
---|-----
 1 | ABC
 1 | DEF
```

You group by `id`, so each row in the result should contain just one `id`. If you select `name` also, without grouping by it, what should be shown in the result for `name`?

It can be either `ABC` or `DEF` but the database engine can not really decide that for you (although MySQL apparently does).

Comment: MySQL picks a random one!  Isn't it strange?  I asked a question about this a few days ago.

Comment: Interesting...in this case at least my id is always unique so it was a good column to group by.  I needed the name of the category too, so I just listed both in the select and group by.  Seems to work.  Thanks!