# GroupingError: ERROR: column " " must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, group-by

I am trying to create a list of unique patients who have left comments.  The code words fine until I upload to heroku where it doesnt work in postgresql.

This is my Ruby .erb code to create the list:

```
<% @comments.group(:patient_id).each_with_index do |comment, index| %>
    <div class="profile-post color-one">
       <span class="profile-post-numb"><%= index+1 %></span>
        <div class="profile-post-in">
            <h3 class="heading-xs"><a><%= link_to "#{comment.patient.first_name} #{comment.patient.last_name}", comment_path(comment) %></a></h3>
            <p>Lastest comment from <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago<i class="pull-right"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_comment_path(comment) %> <%= link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete'} %></i></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

@comments is defined in the controller as:

```
def index
  @comments = current_clinician.comments.order("created_at desc")
end
```

heroku logs give me this as the error message:

> ```
> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "comments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>
> LINE 1: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE  comments"."clini...
>                ^
> SELECT "comments".* *FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."clinician_id" = $1 GROUP BY patient_id  ORDER BY created_at desc
> ```

I have tried the solutions from a other SO questions, such as [20942477](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942477/groupingerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an). Which said that I should add the field comments.id to my group clause:

```
<% @comments.group(:patient_id, :"comments.id").each_with_index do |comment, index| %>
```

This gets rid of the error on heroku but defeats the purpose of the group command - it no longer only shows unique patients but instead lists all of them.

I also tried the solutions from  [1780893](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780893/postgres-partial-column-in-select-group-by-column-must-appear-in-the-group-b).  Which said that I should change the ORDER BY:

```
@comments = current_clinician.comments.order("substring(created_at,1.8) desc")
```

Which gives this error locally:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: substring: SELECT
>   "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."clinician_id" = ? ORDER
>   BY substring(created_at,1.8) desc

I realize this is a common problem, I am inexperienced with SQL so I am having trouble getting the code so it will work in both my development and production environments.  The answers I have read on SO aren't using Ruby to get SQL and go over my experience level.

Comment: The error is telling you what you're trying to do can't be done this way. In this query only one row will be returned for each distinct patient_id. There may be multiple Comment rows with this patient_id. Say there are 10 comments with the same patient_id - if we select a column (eg it's id) that we are not grouping by, which row of the 10 should this value come from? It's ambiguous, so SQL doesn't let you do it. You can only use a column you're grouping over or the output of a function which aggregates the grouped rows, like COUNT or SUM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot combine `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY some_column` in Postgres because that's a contradiction (unless it selects from a single table and `some_column` is its PK). All non-aggregated columns (used in the `SELECT`, `HAVING` or `ORDER BY` clause outside an aggregate function) must be in the `GROUP BY` list - where the primary key column(s) cover(s) all columns of a table. Else it would be undefined which value to pick from the aggregated set.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> When `GROUP BY` is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it
> is not valid for the `SELECT` list expressions to refer to ungrouped
> columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column
> is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would
> otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped
> column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a
> subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the
> ungrouped column.

<sub>A certain other RDBMS is known to play dirty tricks here and allow this and pick arbitrary values...</sub>

You seem to want a list of unique patients that have commented, with the *latest* comment each. The simplest way in Postgres is with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (patient_id) *
FROM   comments
WHERE  clinician_id = $1
ORDER  BY patient_id, created_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

But this won't fly with SQLite - which should not be in the loop to begin with. See:

- [Generic Ruby solution for SQLite3 "LIKE" or PostgreSQL "ILIKE"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249059/generic-ruby-solution-for-sqlite3-like-or-postgresql-ilike/11278943#11278943)

`NULLS LAST` is only relevant if `created_at` can be NULL:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, that was a very helpful answer. I have switched to use PostreSQL locally and `DISTINCT ON` is giving me a list of unique patients: `@comments.order("patient_id, created_at DESC").select('ON (patient_id) *').uniq.each_with_index do |comment, index|` The patients are now ordered in the order they were created in my `seed.rb` file - so in the order in which they were created. Do you have a recommendation for how to get them ordered by the `created_at` of their latest comment?

Comment: @Skiapex: Wrap this query into an outer query with a different `ORDER BY`. Here are detailed instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619117/select-all-threads-and-order-by-the-latest-one/24623210#24623210