# Group and count products on items from orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have these three models:

```
class Order
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  has_many :orders, through: :items
  has_many :items
end
```

And I need to make a list of how many of each product are in the orders from a given date range.

I have a scope to get all orders in a date range:

```
Order.date_range(from, to)
```

Now I need to group and count; there are `product_id` and `units` fields on the item model.

I have seen solutions but just in cases with two tables (order>product) but not with three (order>item>product).

Comment: can't you just call count on the AREL lookup? this would be performed in sql and should be performant

Comment: I don't know. I have just used Arel because of some rails deprecation warning.

Comment: sry my bad. I forget that arel has been merged into core. by arel I mean the ActiveRecord_Relation object, i.e. Order.date_range(from, to).count

Comment: I tried using joins, includes, etc. But can't make it work.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722426/793330

Comment: Was looking for an AR solution. Thanks.

Comment: as a comment, why an item has many items? 
taking this aside, I think that you can ask for items directly and not for orders, it can simplify things, think in something like this `Item.joins(:orders).where(orders: {date: from..to}).group('items.product_id').sum('units')` tell me if it helps you and I will create the answer.

Comment: Thank you xploshioOn. Running that, throws this error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "items.category" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Adding `.select("items.*")` does not solve it. Leaving out the grouping it does work, but I need the group.

Comment: btw, the has many items thing was a copy failure. It's edited on the question.

Comment: try letting the group part like this `...group(:product_id).sum...`

Comment: If I do so `Item.joins(:order).where(orders: {created_at: @from..@to}).group(:product_id).sum('units')` I get the same error. I do not know if it is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661654/1706309.

Comment: Try `Item.joins(:order).where(orders: {created_at: @from..@to}).group(:product_id).pluck('items.product_id, sum(items.units)')` or please provide desired result.

Comment: That gaves me the same error. So I added category and got the same error with code, and added it to and it worked: `Item.joins(:order).where(orders: {created_at: @from..@to}).group('product_id, category, code').pluck('items.product_id, sum(items.units)')`.

Comment: awesome @pzin, if you are ok with it, I could create the answer to close this one.

Comment: Yes, please. I'll accept it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the relation `has_many :products, through: :items` to the Order model.

Then `Order.date_range(from, to).joins(:products).group(:product_id).count` (You can also do `group('products.id')`)

If the `items.units` column isn't always 1 and needs to be summed across you can do: `Order.date_range(from, to).joins(:products).group(:product_id).sum(:units)`

The return will be a hash of `{product1.id => count(product1.id), ...}` or `{product1.id => sum(units1), ...}` respectively for each product in the order.

Comment: Both answers are working well. I will accept this one, because it feels more the rails way and it is faster (0.0897 vs 0.3538). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you can ask for items directly and not for orders, it can simplify things, working with just 2 and not 3 tables.

```
Item.joins(:order).where(orders: {created_at: @from..@to}).group('product_id, category, code').pluck('items.product_id, sum(items.units)')
```