# Problem with MySQL query translated to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a query that worked fine on MySQL and now doesn't on PostgreSQL
This is the query:

```
  SELECT "users".* 
    FROM "users" 
    JOIN "favorites" ON "favorites"."user_id" = "users"."id"
   WHERE users.id NOT IN (2)
     AND favorites.favoritable_id IN (1)
GROUP BY favorites.user_id 
ORDER BY RANDOM() 
   LIMIT 5
```

This is the error:

> column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I have looked up this error but couldn't really find out what I must to do fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL (and SQLite for that matter) do not require you to specify every column in the `GROUP BY` clause that are not wrapped in aggregate functions (IE: MIN, MAX, COUNT, SUM, etc).  This is [by design](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), and is also ANSI spec.  However, this means that the values for those columns will be arbitrary -- they can not be guaranteed every time the query is run.

PostgreSQL/Oracle/SQL Server require you to either specify each column not wrapped in aggregate functions in the group by, or re-write the query so it is not necessary.  Use:

```
  SELECT u.*
    FROM USERS u
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM FAVORITES f
                  WHERE f.user_id = u.id
                    AND f.favoritable_id = 1)
     AND u.id != 2
ORDER BY RANDOM()
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Can I still use the IN () syntax? I use that because normally tons of values will be there, not just one.

Comment: I never used this EXISTS before (probably because I suck with pure SQL and only used mysql in my life) but, is it preferred instead of joins (where applicable) or is this specific to this case?

Comment: @Draiken: Yes, if you aren't returning columns from the table you're joining to - `IN` or `EXISTS` are preferable.  Because using a join can inflate the result set if a parent record has more than one child.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL is awfully lax when it comes to the `GROUP BY`-clause. In MySQL, you can add columns to your select clause that are not in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate functions. Other RDBMS do not allow this, as it makes no sense semantically. MySQL just returns more or less random row values that fit the given query.

From the [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.  [...]
>   MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.

What you have to do is, find out what the query is supposed to do and rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in PostgreSQL is the distinct on clause:

select distinct on (col1, col2) * from users;

this will do pretty much what mysql was doing.