# rails activerecord arel group_by something and selecting a max(col) record for each group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I've got a table of visits(person, visit_type, date, ...), I would like to group by visit_type and person and then select the record in each group that has the MAX(date). I'm pretty sure it should be simple using query algebra rather than writing SQL, but can't seem to get it to work. I thought it would be something like:

```
Visit.group(:visit_type, :person).having("date = MAX(date)")
```

But that does not choose the single record from each group.

EDIT: Ahhh! after a bit more investigation - it turns out the above does work! Yay!

EDIT: Ahhh! It works on sqlite and mySql, but not on postgres, something to do with stricter implementation of the group_by function according to the standard. Boo, rubbish! This means I'm still looking for an answer.

EDIT: I do not think this gives correct results every time on sqlite.

Comment: Not sure how to mark as correct, perhaps I should just remove? Suggestions...

Comment: It's a good question/answer, I would leave it. I learned something from it :)

Comment: See edit - not working on postgres, I get the error discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql). Still looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: You sure you don't want to use SQL? It would be pretty simple.

Comment: I'm up for any [elegant] solution now!

Comment: This works but it returns an array ... 
Visit.group(:visit_type, :person).maximum(:date)

Comment: I revised my answer below, I think this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what I'm going with for the moment:

```
Visit.all.group_by{|v| [v.visit_type,v.person]}.map{|key, value| value.inject{|memo, visit| memo.date > visit.date ? memo : visit}}
```

I know it's not pretty, but it's my daughter's 6th birthday, so I've got to go!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Visit.joins('LEFT JOIN visits v2 on visits.visit_type = v2.visit_type AND visits.person = v2.person AND visits.date > v2.date')
```

Comment: Nope - getting duplicates, but I have a solution using ruby that works, even though it's a bit hideous.