# GROUP BY query that works in MySQL is rejected by PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this query (that works fine in MySQL):

```
SELECT units.*, activity_logs.created_at 
FROM "units" left join activity_logs on units.id=activity_logs.unit_id 
GROUP BY units.id 
ORDER BY activity_logs.created_at desc
```

Postgres gives this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "activity_logs.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I know that Postgres is right SQL-wise but how do I get what I want? That is the latest activity_log entry for each unit joined with all of the units table?

Thanks in advance!

- Jacob

Comment: It's best to always mention your PostgreSQL version. If possible please also include table definitions and a little sample data.

Comment: See the very last entry in the [“Features We Do _Not_ Want” list](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Features_We_Do_Not_Want).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error explains it: you need to use an aggregate function to make this deterministic, eg:

```
SELECT units.*, max(activity_logs.created_at)
FROM "units" left join activity_logs on units.id=activity_logs.unit_id 
GROUP BY units.id 
ORDER BY max(activity_logs.created_at) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks - that did it! Can you explain it a little - I really don't quite get the difference between my solution and yours (except that yours works :-)

Comment: @jriff Your original query relies on non-standard behaviour by MySQL, where you can "SELECT a, b FROM sometable GROUP BY a" and it'll just pick the first `b` it comes across. This is non-deterministic and not permitted by the SQL standard; the result can change depending on details of how the SQL engine executes the query, like index vs sequential scan choice. To do that in PostgreSQL you can use `DISTINCT ON (...)` but it's usually better to use an aggregate on the non-grouped column(s) so that PostgreSQL knows which of the candidate results to return no matter how the query gets executed.

Comment: @jriff BTW, in older PostgreSQL versions you have to explicitly `GROUP BY` all columns, as older versions weren't smart enough to figure out that grouping by the primary key meant that all other columns were automatically part of the group as a consequence.

Comment: Actually for some reason the order of the result is backwards - I need the latest activity_logs.created_at to be the first result. Here it is the last? (But in MySQL it is correct). Do you know why?

Comment: @jriff It shouldn't be... did you forget the `desc` sort modifier? Otherwise, please provide sample data and schema on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The problem is that all of the units that have no related activity_logs are returned first. After them the sorting is fine. So it is kind of working :-) I did remember the 'desc' and that part is working.

Comment: @jriff OK, that's different, you want to use the `NULLS LAST` sort modifier, as per the PostgreSQL manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html