# Must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function (PostgreSQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have query like this :

```
select u.fullname ,s.schedate,
sum(case when s.isvisiting =1 then s.isvisiting else 0 end) as visit ,
count(s.custid) as cust, 
sum(case when s.isclosing = 1 then s.isclosing else 0 end)as orders 
from vmstrschedule s JOIN vmsmsuser u ON u.usercode = s.salesmanid 
where u.branchid = 'BLL' group by u.fullname
```

but it shows error like this :

> must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

it works in MySQL , but when I tried it in PostgreSQL it didn't work . I want to display data like this , per month :

[image]

but if I used this query :

```
select u.fullname,s.schedate,
sum(case when s.isvisiting =1 then s.isvisiting else 0 end) as visit ,
count(s.custid) as cust, 
sum(case when s.isclosing = 1 then s.isclosing else 0 end)as orders 
from vmstrschedule s JOIN vmsmsuser u ON u.usercode = s.salesmanid 
where u.branchid = 'BLL' group by u.fullname,s.schedate
order by u.fullname
```

it will shows data like this :

[image]

Comment: It "works" in MySQL because MySQL chooses to return random (they call it "indeterminate") data instead of rejecting an invalid grouping clause: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/  MySQL is the only DBMS to allow this, all others (including Postgres) will reject such a group by clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "works" you mean it arbitrarily selects one of the possible `schedate` values for each group, you're correct. However, postgresql and most other SQL products want you to be explicit about what value they should select

If all the values are the same within each group, putting it in either the `GROUP BY` clause or an arbitrary aggregate (e.g. `MAX(s.schedate)`) should work. If the values are different, please tell the server which one it should select - the `MIN`, or `MAX` would usually be appropriate.

Comment: nice . really help

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.fullname ,s.schedate,
sum(case when s.isvisiting =1 then s.isvisiting else 0 end) as visit ,
count(s.custid) as cust, 
sum(case when s.isclosing = 1 then s.isclosing else 0 end)as orders 
from vmstrschedule s JOIN vmsmsuser u ON u.usercode = s.salesmanid 
where u.branchid = 'BLL' group by u.fullname, s.schedate
```

should work

Comment: @jack Do not select s.schedate if you don't need it in the output (skip it in both select and group by)