# Postgres: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to construct a query that selects a groupname and the name of the CD with the highest sales. The schema looks something like

group(groupName, groupCode)

cd(cdTitle, numberSold, groupCode)

I have constructed a query like this:

```
SELECT mg.groupName, cd.cdTitle, MAX(cd.numberSold) as maxSold
FROM musicalGroup mg, cd cd
WHERE cd.groupCode = mg.groupCode
GROUP BY mg.groupCode
```

But I am receiving the error

> ERROR:  column "cd.cdtitle" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

If I remove the cd.cdtitle from the SELECT statement I am able to get the proper results that display

```
groupname... maxsold
"Test"... 80000
"Test2"... 81000
```

And so forth. Is there any way for me to also retrieve the CD name from this query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `DENSE_RANK()` to identify the top sellers in each musical group.  Note that I chose `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` because the former will allow us to identify multiple artists per group who happen to have a tie for the highest sales.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mg.groupName,
           cd.cdTitle,
           cd.numberSold,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cd.groupCode ORDER BY cd.numberSold DESC) dr
    FROM musicalGroup mg
    INNER JOIN cd cd
        ON cd.groupCode = mg.groupCode
)
SELECT t.groupName,
       t.cdTitle,
       t.numberSold AS maxSold
FROM cte t
WHERE t.dr = 1
```

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I made an error when copy and pasting the query. The issue is stemming from me trying to print cd.cdTitle, not  from grouping the code and name. I edited my query to reflect that.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think makes the most sense here.

Comment: Hmm. That seems strange. It's listing every single CD with the artist's highest sales next to it, when what I want is ONE CD from each artist with the highest sales.

Comment: @JCDJulian You only gave a broken query, with zero sample data or expected output.  Next time, please try to ask a better question.  In the meantime, I think my updated answer is what you are looking for.