# Column must appeared in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have this query that will LEFT JOIN between two table and SUM the amount

```
SELECT
    l.code,
    SUM(p.amount)
FROM
    locations l
LEFT JOIN payments p 
ON p.location_code = l.code
GROUP by l.code
```

It working correctly and this is the output

[image]

Right now I want to select more column, example location name

```
SELECT
    l.code,
    l.location.name,
    SUM(p.amount)
FROM
    locations l
LEFT JOIN payments p 
ON p.location_code = l.code
GROUP by l.code
```

However I faced this error

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "l.location_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3:  l.location_name,
```

Adding location_name to GROUP BY its not an option if I need select more column in the future.

How should I modify my query to support more column select?

DB fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4485d0b1d37b8b476f3f513649a6ebfb

Comment: yes, add `l.location_name` to the GROUP BY list, and notice that `l.location.name != l.location_name`. Refer : [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9c35d9307a0fe1f35618ad17c00a542f)

Comment: @cyberfly If adding `location_name` to the group by results in a different value, then a `code` can have more than one `location_name`. But you want to have a single `code` and a single `location_name`. So which `location_name` should be displayed? You might get any of them, and what's the use of that?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan actually this is simpler version of the real table that I want to query. Let see if in future I want to select more column, it does not make sense to keep adding the column into GROUP BY which will lead to different result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe put the `SUM()` into a correlated subquery:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d3021a2fd0b32b79d098aeebc9f9cea2)

```
SELECT
    l.*,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payments p WHERE p.location_code = l.code)
FROM
    locations l
```

Comment: Thanks alternative view into the problem that I want to solve. This way everything can become easier such as want to paginate the records

Comment: Thanks for accepting, please do not forget to upvote as well. I would appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also define `location.code` as the primary key of the table (or declare it as unique).  Then you can just aggregate by that column and select all other columns:

```
SELECT l.*, SUM(p.amount)
FROM locations l LEFT JOIN
     payments p 
     ON p.location_code = l.code
GROUP BY l.code;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8a2bb3338277524c49d9a2ae5ee43818) is a db<>fiddle.

This is *standard* behavior for SQL; it is based on something called "functional dependence".

Comment: Thanks good info, no wonder if I try to join using primary key there is no problem. Will upvote your answer because I cant change the table structure

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    l.code,
    l.location_name,
    SUM(p.amount)
FROM
    locations l
LEFT JOIN payments p 
ON p.location_code = l.code
GROUP by l.code,l.location_name
```

If changing group by is not what you want, you might have to use subquery:

```
SELECT
    l.code,
    (select location_name from locations l2 where l.code=l2.code),
    SUM(p.amount)
FROM
    locations l
LEFT JOIN payments p 
ON p.location_code = l.code
GROUP by l.code
```

Comment: this will bring undesired result, for example if I need to select more column

Comment: I modified the answer with a subquery. Hope it helps.

Comment: @TomYeh That subquery needs a LIMIT 1 else it will almost certainly return multiple results and raise an exception.

Comment: You're right.  Basically it depends on your requirement to put more restricted condition in the where clause to get the one you want.